# traverse ordered array once to check if any two elements satisfy (together) condition

Tags: c#

How would you check, having an ordered array of int elements: `int[]`, if any two elements have a *sum* of a given value, while traversing the array *only once*?
I solved this by traversing the array *twice*. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you even tried *anything* to achieve this? Why should we make your job? Please write what exactly you´ve tried and where you got problems.

Comment: *I solved this by traversing the array twice.* ~ do you mind sharing your code then?

Comment: Are the two elements next to each other? Then it should be easy.

Comment: If not I doubt therte´s a way without at least two iterations.

Comment: Please read [“How Do I Ask a Good Question?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @TheSkimek I understood it that way that if you imagine an `int[]` with let's say numbers from 1 to 100. Now he want's to get all *pairs* that have a sum of 50.

Comment: I think this should belong at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but you need to add your code.

Comment: Start with a pointer at both ends. If the sum of these 2 values is too small, increment the left pointer. If the sum is too large, decrement the right pointer.

Comment: Thanks Dennis it worked with your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to scan from *both* ends (`left` and `right`) simultaneously: after moving `left` on step ahead, adjust the `right` border; in this case you read each array's item just once. Something like this:

```
private static Tuple<int, int> FindPair(int[] data, int sum) {
  int left = -1;
  int right = data.Length;

  while (left < right) {
    left += 1;

    if (left >= right)
      break;

    int leftValue = data[left];

    // Having new left border, we have to adjust right border
    for (int r = right - 1; r > left; --r) {
      int rightValue = data[r];

      if (rightValue + leftValue == sum)
        return new Tuple<int, int>(left, r);
      else if (rightValue + leftValue > sum)
        right -= 1;
    }
  }

  return new Tuple<int, int>(-1, -1);
}
```

Tests:

```
int[] data = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12};

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(4, 20)
  .Select(sum => $"{sum,2}: {FindPair(data, sum)}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
 4: (-1, -1)
 5: (0, 1)
 6: (0, 2)
 7: (0, 3)
 8: (1, 3)
 9: (0, 4)
10: (1, 4)
11: (2, 4)
12: (0, 5)
13: (1, 5)
14: (0, 6)
15: (1, 6)
16: (2, 6)
17: (3, 6)
18: (-1, -1)
19: (4, 6)
20: (-1, -1)
21: (-1, -1)
22: (5, 6)
23: (-1, -1)
```

Comment: Do we really want to answer questions that don´t show any own affords?

Comment: I gave +1 because i normally do this i was far from the pc and too curious to wait longer. Just now i wanted to post a solution that dennis helped me think of but Dmitry already did thank you Dmitry.

Comment: Awesome. I didnt know about Tuple as a type. Thanks dmitry